# Django: set foreignkey to model of which `abstract` True...?

Tags: django, database, migration, database-migration

I've designed some `model` structures in `django`:

```
class Symbol(BaseModel):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True    

class DetailSymbol1(Symbol):
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class DailyData(BaseModel):
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(DetailSymbol1)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

After `makemigrations` and `migrate` done, I created some model objects:

```
In [1]: a = DetailSymbol1.objects.create(field1="a", field2="b")

In [2]: a.dailydata_set.create(field3="c")
Out[2]: <DailyData: DailyData object>

In [3]: a.dailydata_set.create(field3="d")
Out[3]: <DailyData: DailyData object>

In [4]: DailyData.objects.count()
Out[4]: 2
```

Now, What I want to do is to make `Symbol` model NOT `abstract` model and make `DailyData` have `ForeignKey` to `Symbol`, not `DetailSymbol1`. Here is the final code:

```
class Symbol(BaseModel):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class DetailSymbol1(Symbol):
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class DailyData(BaseModel):
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(Symbol)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

When I tried to `migration`, this prompt occured:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'symbol_ptr' to detailsymbol1 without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

I have no idea what should I do with this message.

How can I deal with it without losing my data?

Need your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new foreign key to `Symbol` while keeping the old one.

```
class DailyData(BaseModel):
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(DetailSymbol1)
    new_symbol = models.ForeignKey(Symbol)
```

Then create a data migration to populate `new_symbol`.

Finally you can remove the old foreign key to `DetailSymbol1`, and rename `new_symbol` to `symbol`.

Comment: This one is simpler !

Answer (score 0):

You get this message because you did not provide default value for your field. Since you already have your objects you will get this message, unless you either have your database cleared or you provide default value. Or the other option can be setting null=True to your field - this will enable you to save objects without supplying value for your field symbol.

Furthermore Django will only generate tables for subclasses of models.Model, so it will not generate table for your Symbol in the first place. But when you make new migrations and you delete abstract, it will create new table. You will not lose your data, simply provide null=True or a default value

Comment: Thanks, but how can I set default value as current holding `symbol`'s id ? What should I type in the prompt?

Comment: You do not have to type anything in your console. If you did it would assign this id to every single object without value. In your field change your `symbol = models.ForeignKey(Symbol)` to `symbol = models.ForeignKey(Symbol, null=True, blank=True)` - then run makemigrations and migrate and all will be good

Comment: If I do that, all `DailyData` objects would lose the `symbol` information.... I don't want make that happens..... because I have a tons of `DailyData` objects....T_T

Comment: Nope they will not. By adding null=True to your model you will say to your database that this field can be null (empty). This will not erase your field data. If you are unsure - make a database copy and try out what I`m saying

Comment: I did and the `detailsymbol1` table has erased `symbol` col!!

Comment: `DetailSymbol1` never had a `symbol` column. Only `DailyData` have it.